# Full Stop/Capital letters in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to format some text and although I have used various tpes of ProperCase function in the past this time it's not quite what I am after.  My example text would be something like this :-

> this is a TEST to see if everything is correct.  once this has been done please let Mark know.

How I want it to be format is as follows

> This is a test to see if everything it correct.  Once this has been done please let Mark know.

In essence I only want a capital letter either at the beginning of the text string or after a full stop, is this possible?

Thanks PD

Comment: Yes, but what if you have a text like `"This is a TEST because I want to see if John Doe did it right"`?

Comment: What if the sentence contained the word `Test`, would that stay the same as `Mark` does. Or change the way `test` does?

Comment: If anything could do this, Google would have already applied it to YouTube comments.

Comment: Is possible, but T-SQL is absolutely not the right tool for that. Transform it in the client, *prior* to inserting the value. If you insist in having inside SQL then at least use [SQLCLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR).

Comment: @RemusRusanu OP's example preserves the capitalisation of proper nouns. So I don't know how a language other than T-SQL is going to differentiate between "Doctor Bone is a leading figure on bone research" and "I need to make this research paper quota, I'm going to doctor bone research results"

Comment: I'm not a machine-learning/yacc/regex/clever-ascii-art expert, so I cant really answer how far can you go down that path, but I think you can go pretty far. OK, maybe I shouldn't say so certain 'Is possible', consider it more like 'If is possible and you can do it, then...'. The gist of my comment is that T-SQL is not the right tools for the job.

Comment: You'd need a table (or more) containing exceptions to the rule, basically a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the code below. I'm pretty sure SQL is not the best tool but it was an interesting exercise. The code below works with the following assumptions:

There's no exceptions for words like "Mark" in your example, just 2 rules for the beginning and full stop.

There's always a space after a full stop (it will be fairly easy to change the code below though if this is not the case)

```
declare @input as nvarchar(max) = 'this is a TEST to see if everything is correct. once this has been done please let Mark know.'
declare @result as nvarchar(max) = ''

;with cte
as
(
    select substring(@input, 1, 1) as Ch, 1 as Idx

    union all

    select substring(@input, cte.Idx + 1, 1) as Ch, cte.Idx + 1 as Idx
    from cte
    where cte.Idx < len(@input)
)

select
    @result = @result + case when Idx > 2 and (select Ch from cte t where t.Idx = cte.Idx - 2) = '.'
    then upper(Ch)
    else  
        case Idx
        when 1 then upper(Ch)
        else lower(Ch) 
        end
    end
from cte

print @result
```